# js fuction to compare 2 items for equality

Tags: algorithm, function, comparison, equality

Trying to create a function that would compare 2 items based on equality. Unfortunately, it doesn't work properly please help.

```
//This is what I have so far:
function checkEquality(a,b){
    if (a===b) {
        return "The type and values are equal."
   }else if (a==b && typeof a !== typeof b) {
    return "The type is different."
  }else if (a!==b){
    return "The value and type are different."
  } 
}
console.log(checkEquality(1,true))
console.log(checkEquality(0,"0"))
console.log(checkEquality(1,1))
```

Comment: I have run your code, and it is showing everything correctly: type different, type different, type and values are same.

Comment: I was hoping that for input 1, true it would return "The value and type are different."

Comment: `1 == true` is truthy in javascript, so according to it, only type is different.

Comment: Thank you so much! It makes so much sense now!